# Joomla 3.1 JDatabase Union Query

Tags: mysql, database, joomla, union, joomla3.1

Would anyone be able to show how to do a union with the jDatabase `query` object?

The functionality looks to be in Joomla, I just can't find any documentation with working examples...

The query I'm wanting to achieve would normally look like this in plain text:

```
SELECT field1,field2 FROM `#__mycomponent_table1` WHERE field1 = 0
UNION
SELECT field1,field2 FROM `#__mycomponent_table2` WHERE field1 = 0
```

EDIT - I've tried this:

```
$db = $this->getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->union(array('SELECT field1,field2 FROM `#__mycomponent_table1` WHERE field1 = 0','SELECT field1,field2 FROM `#__mycomponent_table2` WHERE field1 = 0'));
```

Gives Me:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 15' at line 1 SQL= LIMIT 0, 15 SQL='

Comment: could you provide an example of your 2 database queries please?

Comment: A relevant resource for researchers: [Using the union methods in database queries](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_union_methods_in_database_queries)

Answer (score 1):

Basically `JDatabaseQuery::Union` works by appending:

```
UNION (somequery) UNION (someotherquery)
```

to your `$query`.

The later queries need to be strings which you can generate from jdatabasequery separately and converting to strings.  So in other words the later queries are basically treated as subqueries

```
->union(array('somequery','someotherquery'))
```

Updating

The tricky part is that the query needs to already include the first query and then `union()` adds the additional queries to that.

In Joomla to diagnose queries try

```
echo $query->dump();
```

then you can see what is wrong in the generated query.

Another update

Also I wanted to add that you need to understand that in general JDatabaseQuery  can use one and only one SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE but UNION provides a way to work around that restriction when it comes to SELECT. However because it does basically put together two SELECT statements it's more complicated than just adding another clause to the first SELECT. That is you cannot chain union()  In essence  you should think of it as (query1) UNION (query2) .. you need the two queries to do the operation.
And basically you need to do special handling to put the two parts together.

This works by creating the string: UNION (query2)  and  concatenating that to query1.

So here's an example that would give you the list of all article and weblinks titles and aliases.

```
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select('title, alias')
    ->from('#__content');
    // Clone the query, replace the FROM clause.
    $sub = clone($query);
    $sub->clear('from');
    $sub->from('#__weblinks');

    $subunion = $db->getQuery(true);

    $subunion->union($sub);
    $string = $query . ' ' .  $subunion->union;
    $db->setQuery($string);
    $matches = $db->loadObjectList(); 
    var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.  `$query = $db->getQuery(true); $query->union(array('select xxxxx','select yyyyyy'));`

Comment: It gives me `SQL= You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 15' at line 1 SQL= LIMIT 0, 15 SQL=`

Comment: You have to have the first part in $query then add the second part using ->union()

i.e. $query->select('name')
->from('#__sometable')
->union(array('some query here'));

Answer (score 1):

**Don't confuse UNION with JOIN**

"UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set." [UNION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

So first you need to understand if you need a JOIN or a UNION.

**How to use UNION in Joomla**

Statistically speaking (inspecting the Joomla code-base) UNION is not so widely used like a JOIN.

Basically Joomla does provide at least two methods on the `JDatabaseQuery` class. `union` and `unionAll`. Unfortunately I am not able to provide you with a query that actually works.

The only component using it in the CMS is the com_finder indexer, if you want to study it.

**Don't be afraid of plain old queries if you really need them**

While using `JDatabaseQuery` does provide an easy way to build queries and also makes them compatible with multiple database drivers, there is nothing wrong in writing the queries yourself, if you need to, especially if you need just MySQL support.

`JDatabase & Co` have lots of cool features but are by no means perfect. They solve 99% of the query needs that you have. There are occasions where you need more complex expressions that are not covered by them.

In the end, the query given to the database engine is still a query, regardless how it was build.

Comment: Thanks Vanetin - I've checked the union and unionAll stuff but when I try using them it just borks.  There is plenty of stuff on the bug tracker about them being broken but I've no idea if they are correct.  I definitely need union and not a join because there is no field to join them with, I just want the like fields to be stacked on top of each other.

Comment: THey actually are correct (reading the unit tests gives you the best illustration of how to use them), but they are not like other sql statements in that they operate on complete queries.   In the old platform tracker there were some examples because they were used in an early version of tags.

Answer (score 0):

add your union query like below .
for more follow [joomla doc](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase):-

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = "
  SELECT *
    FROM . . . ";
$db->setQuery($query);
$row = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: This uses old Joomla coding standards

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the `join()` method like so:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('a.*', 'b.username', 'b.name')))
 ->from($db->quoteName('#__content', 'a'))
 ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__users', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.created_by') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.id') . ')')
 ->where($db->quoteName('b.username') . ' LIKE \'a%\'');

$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
```

This is simply an example query that will select all the articles for the users that have a username starting with **"a"**.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Lodder but I need to select like data from several tables - I'll edit my original question to reflect this...